# Calcular o menor elemento de uma lista

Tags: java, algoritmo, lista

Dada um sequência de números inteiros (lidos via `Scanner`), determine o menor destes valores.

Meu código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenorValorSequencia {

    public static void main (String args []) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int [] variavel = new int [10];
    for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++) {
    variavel[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    int menorValor = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++) {
            if (variavel[i]<menorValor) {
                menorValor = variavel[i];
            }
        System.out.println (menorValor(i)); // erro: não pode achar variável menorvalor
        }
    }
}
```

O código em Java para este problema pode ser feito assim?

Comment: Por favor, não use negrito no texto todo, o recurso é para dar destaque a pontos que sejam importantes apenas

Comment: E você está tratando variável como se fosse um método, menorValor é uma variável, não existe essa chamada `menorValor(i)`. Remova o `(i)` na frente.

Comment: Alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não sabe como fazê-lo. Assim ajuda a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 6):

Tem três erros: o valor inicial precisa ser o maior inteiro possível; tem que mandar imprimir a variável e não um função; e a impressão deve ocorrer após o laço terminar e não dentro dele.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MenorValorSequencia {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] variavel = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) variavel[i] = sc.nextInt();
        int menorValor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) if (variavel[i] < menorValor) menorValor = variavel[i];
        System.out.println(menorValor);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OcyRD2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xaiejsfk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/LesserValue.java).

Comment: Eu gosto da ideia de usar o primeiro valor lido como `menorValor` inicial.

Comment: @iTSangar é uma boa ideia sim

Comment: Quando fomos fazer esse algoritmo na aula lembro da professora usar esse exemplo: Precisamos descobrir qual filho de uma família é o mais bonito, se tiver só um filho logo ele é o mais bonito. E assim será até que tenha outro filho pra fazer a comparação.

Answer (score 3):

O valor inicial de `int menorValor = 0;` é o problema, para esse valor ser alterado é necessária a entrada de um valor negativo.

E aqui não é um array `System.out.println (menorValor(i));`

O correto seria: `System.out.println (menorValor);`

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu corrigi o código como você falou, que agora executa, mas imprime 10 vezes o mesmo resultado correto. Por gentileza, como corrigir?

Comment: Seu `System.out.println(menorValor)` esta dentro do `for` mude ele para depois da chave logo após ele

Comment: Muito obrigado. Como vocês já perceberam, eu sou Iniciante em Java. Agora executou perfeitamente.